# Markov Chains: Expected visit time when the visit probability is less than 1

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, markov-chains

I'm rather new to Markov Chains and I was reading about them in the book "Randomized Algorithms" by Motwani and Raghavan when i stumbled into a somewhat confusing definition. I tried looking for similar questions but they all seem to refer to additional concepts and I would like to get a feedback on the book specific case to asses whether my understanding is correct.

Specifically I got confused reading the following extract about a the definition of $h$ the expected number of steps needed to get from a state $i$ to a state $j$. The scenario is that of discrete Markov Chains with a finite or countable number of states, associated to a transition matrix P (which is row-stochastic). I report here the relevant extract of the text.

[image]

As you can see $h$ follows a standard definition for the expected value, but I am not able to fully grasp the last sentence. To me it looks like it is a logical deduction the author does with respect to the definition of $h$, and not as a special case of the definition (but I may be wrong since English is not my primary language), and to me this does not seem to make sense.

Intuitively, it would make sense that whenever I have the possibility to reach a region that completely prevents me to get back to the state $j$ the expected time to get back to it will grow indefenetly. However, looking at the formula of $h$ I could rather easily come up with a example that seems to falsify the authors' claim. An example could be represented by the following graph where we could assume uniform probability for the outgoing edges (i.e. $1/2$ for all the edges except the self-loop).
[image]
In this case it appears to me that $f_{ij}$ would be equal to $1/2$,since I can get to it only half of the times when starting from $i$, and hence $f_{ij} < 1$, but $h_{ij} = 1/2 \neq \infty$ (since only $r_{ij}^{(1)}= 1/2 >0$, while $\forall \ t>1\ \ r_{ij}^{(t)}=0$ since it is impossible to end up in j for the first time in exactly $t>1$ steps when starting from $i$). In this case the issue would be that $r_{ij}^{(t)}$ becomes exactly $0$ for all the values $t>t_{0}$ for some $t_{0}$, preventing the contibution of infinitely many positive contributions in $h_{ij}$. In any case, even when there are infinitely many (but not all, since $f_{ij} < 1$) paths that lead from i to j, I guess we may end up with a convergent sum for $h_{ij}$, which would again prove against the definition.

So my doubt is mainly the following: is the definition of the book somewhat imprecise and the claim $f_{ij}<1 \implies h_{ij} = \infty$ is more of a convention that does not follow the standard case, or am I getting something wrong with my reasoning?
Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: IMO this is poorly described in this exposition. What is intended is for $t \mapsto r_{ij}^{(t)}$ to be the PMF of the first arrival time to $j$ from $i$, say $\tau$. But $\tau$ itself is meant to be defined to be $\inf \{ t : X_t=j \}$ and then we compute its expectation conditional on $X_0=i$. This inf is $+\infty$ with probability $1-f_{ij}$, so when $f_{ij}<1$ the expectation is infinite. I suppose technically $t=\infty$ can be inferred to be one of the summands here but that feels like abuse of notation at best to me.

Comment: This definition makes more sense to me. It's again based on the "convention" that $inf\{\emptyset\}=+\infty$ but al least this is a known result which clicks with the intuition behind the meaning of $h_{ij}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer by [@jjcluu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/887187/jjcluu) and comment by [@Ian](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83396/ian) and looking at other definitions for the hitting time I understood that the one given in the book is rather imprecise, leading to a clash between the intuition and the mathematical formula. I will summarize here the main points.

As suggested, a better definition would be the following. Let $Y$ be a random variable that takes the value of $\text{inf}\{t\ |\ X_t=j\}$, then

$$h_{ij}=\text{E}(\ Y\ |\ X_0 = i)$$

At this point we can observe that $Y=+\infty$, i.e. there is a random walk on the associated graph that does not visit $j$, may happend with probability $1-f_{ij}$ when $X_0 = i$. Hence when $f_{ij} < 1$ it follows that $Pr[Y=+\infty | X_0=i] > 0$ and so that $h_{ij} = +\infty$ , which is the result expected and matches the intuition.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly pointed out, $f_{ij}$ is defined as an infinite sum, so you are summing over infinitely many first passage/return probabilities (the $r_{ij}^{(t)}$), where there are possibly some transitions that might leave you in a loop never returning back to your desired $j$. Hence, if you get stuck in some sort of loop then you may never reach $j$ from $i$ in a finite number of steps (which is what the $h_{ij}$ counts).

Comment: that is what I was thinking when reasoning about the meaning of $h_{ij}$, but the formula the book authors proposed seemed a bit misleading